# Delete function throwing mySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

Im having trouble trying to find out why my script wont delete a row in my table.

Each user has a randomkey assigned to them. I need to say delete row in table where random key equals that to the user...

```
<?php 

$userRand = $_GET['Rand'];

$delUser = mysql_query("DELETE from users WHERE randomkey = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($userRand));
        if(! $qResult )
            {
                die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        elseif($qResult )
            {
                echo "deleted"; 
            }

?>
```

the following outputs...

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''111111111' at line 1
```

Comment: not related completly, but for a delete operation you should use POST and not GET. this will prevent some problems (like an image with this script in the url)

Comment: Indeed, POSTs for modifications, GETs _only_ for retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing `'` in your PHP code.

```
$delUser = mysql_query("DELETE from users WHERE randomkey = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($userRand) . "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the SQL-String.

```
$delUser = mysql_query(
    sprintf("DELETE from users WHERE randomkey = '%d'", mysql_real_escape_string($userRand)
);
```